# Why are we use not static attribute to lock not static field?

Tags: c#, static, locking

In C# we use the *static lock* with static fields and *non static lock* with non-static fields. Why is it better than using static lock with non-static fields? Like this:

```
public class A{
   long variable = 0;
   static object sync = new object();
   void Increment(){
       lock (sync){variable++;}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason not to use a `static` lock with a non-static field is simply so that you don't get *unnecessary* conflicts. If the field is on different objects, then they can usually safely be mutated separately - so there's no need for two threads to have to block each-other (which would happen if you used a `static` lock, and two threads were touching *different* objects).

Personally I'd be tempted to just use an `Interlocked.Increment(ref variable);` :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter it *can* be; although in the case shown, it probably wouldn't matter since the lock is so short in duration : there aren't likely to be many true collisions.